# Joda Date converstion

Tags: java, timestamp, jodatime

I have timestamp in format "2009-12-12T23:00:00.000+05:30". I want it to convert it in timestamp so that "+5:30" is applied to it and the timestamp will become "2009-12-13T04:30:00.000"

I have to do with this with joda. 
Any help will be great.

Comment: "2009-12-12T23:00:00.000+05:30" is equivalent to "2009-12-12T17:30:00.000+00:00" (taking away positive offset means subtraction from local time, not addition to local time).

Comment: Yah right....i misunderstood initially. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatter XML_DATE_TIME_FORMAT= ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

DateTime dt = XML_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parseDateTime("2009-12-12T23:00:00.000+05:30");
System.out.println(dt);
```

This converts to my local timezone.